# CaseMilestone on Apex test class

Tags: failing-tests, casemilestone, entitlements

I have been trying to test a business process that uses Case/Entitlements/EntitleMent Processes/ and CaseMilestones. All these components are working just fine and there are not issues whatsoever in any of these flows.

The blocker I'm dealing with is related to a test class that needs to test a method that triggers the all Entitlement flow when a Case is created.

My issue is that the test class doesn't create a CaseMilestone even when the Entitlement Process rules are met by the case in this test method.

**Test Class:**

```
/**
 * Created by carlosnaranjo on 13/12/2021.
 */

@IsTest
public class CaseMilestoneServiceTest {

    @IsTest(SeeAllData=true)
    static void testCloseMilestones() {
        // Given
        List<Case> cases = TestDataFactory.createCases(1);
        //List<Entitlement> entitlements = TestDataFactory.createEntitlements(1);
        List<Entitlement> entitlements = [SELECT Id FROM Entitlement WHERE Name = 'Generic' LIMIT 1];
        List<Account> accounts = TestDataFactory.createAccounts(1);
        Id slaProcessId = [SELECT Id FROM SlaProcess WHERE Name = 'SLA 20' AND IsActive = TRUE LIMIT 1].Id;

        Account acc = accounts[0];
        acc.PersonEmail = 'testCloseMilestones@test.com';
        acc.Number_Of_Cases__c = 0;
        insert acc;

        Id accountId = acc.Id;

        Case c = cases[0];
        Id CaseCarRemarketingComplaintRecordTypeId =
                Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('LP_CRM_Complaint').getRecordTypeId();
        System.debug('Record Type Id: ' + CaseCarRemarketingComplaintRecordTypeId);

        c.RecordTypeId = CaseCarRemarketingComplaintRecordTypeId;
        c.Origin = 'Web';
        c.Status = 'New';
        c.AccountId = accountId;
        c.VehicleOwner__c = 'CarNext';
        c.Entitlement = entitlements[0];
        c.SlaStartDate = System.now();
        insert c;

        // When
        Test.startTest();
        c.Status = 'Waiting for LP confirmation';
        update c;
        Test.stopTest();

        // Then
        Case newCase = [SELECT Status FROM Case WHERE Id = :c.Id];
        Integer caseMileStoneCount = [SELECT COUNT() FROM CaseMilestone WHERE CaseId = :c.Id];

        System.assertEquals('Waiting for LP confirmation', newCase.Status, 'Status should be set to progress');
        System.assertEquals(1, caseMileStoneCount, 'CaseMilestone missing');
    }

}
```

The part that fails is the assertion:

`System.assertEquals(1, caseMileStoneCount, 'CaseMilestone missing');`

If I take the case part of this test class and execute an anonymous apex whit it, the **CaseMileStone** is created correct.

So my question is, it is possible to assert if there are CaseMilestones as part of a test method? There is anything else that needs to be done in order to make it available on a test class?

Comment: would a selector class that wraps your SOQL for `CaseMilestone` help? Then the testmethod can inject a mockSelector class that returns a mock `CaseMilestone` so the rest of your logic can proceed?

Comment: The problem is that the Casemilestone is not been created. Is not an issue of the query....

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're still encountering the issue, but it's worth checking that you're getting the right entitlement back.
We use entitlement versioning so needed to sort the list to ensure we're getting the latest version:

```
SELECT ID FROM SlaProcess WHERE Name = 'Entitlement Name' AND IsActive = true ORDER BY VersionNumber DESC LIMIT 1
```

I wonder if you're encountering similar and you're pulling back an earlier Entitlement Process.